# An enum switch case label

Tags: java

```
            LocalDate currentdate = LocalDate.now();
            Month currentMonth = currentdate.getMonth();
            FrequencyEntity frequencyEntity = null;
            switch (currentMonth) {
                case Month.JANUARY: // Here.
                    frequencyEntity = FrequencyEntity.builder().january(frequency).build();
                    
            }
```

The line I have commented as "Here" causes my IDE to show this: "An enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an enumeration constant.".

[image]

The only possible solution I can envisage is convert the month to String. But this may be not a correct solution.

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Try just JANUARY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the *unqualified* part in the error message. It's not saying you can't use enum values as case labels - it's saying that you can't include the enum name. The code should be:

```java
switch (currentMonth) {
    case JANUARY:
        frequencyEntity = FrequencyEntity.builder().january(frequency).build();
        break;
}
```